How to read a memo attached to a Temporal workflow using TypeScript?
I successfully called upsertMemo in an Activity, but WorkflowExecutionInfo.memo is still empty when I look for it in a list of all worfklow executions obtained via TemporalClient.workflowService.listWorkflowExecutions.
This is my worker code:
const fieldValue = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
upsertMemo({'fieldName': fieldValue});
console.log(`Memo set to ${JSON.stringify(workflowInfo().memo)}`);

Output:
Memo set to {"fieldName":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

This is my consumer code:
const client: Client = await this.temporalService.getClient();
const workflowExecutions = await client.workflowService.listWorkflowExecutions({
  query: "WorkflowType = 'workflowName'", 
  namespace: 'default',            
});
const ids = [];
for await (const execution of workflowExecutions.executions) {
  console.log(`Found workflow ${execution.execution?.workflowId}`);
  const memo = execution.memo;
  console.log(`Memo = ${JSON.stringify(memo)} (${memo})`);
}
O

Output:
Found workflow 2c81a11a-512a-4e56-88b8-00ea5762f81d
Memo = {} ([object Object])

I expected to get {"fieldName":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"} again.
What’s going on here in your opinion?
Thank you for your help.
